# Passing String Array to another class using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Actually I have two ACTIVITIES namely MainActivity and ListVIew .
I want to pass this String array "arr" from MainActivity to ListVIew ..
And the Activity ListVIew will show the List of elements of "arr"

Note: The data in arr is supplied from a database created by me , and it works fine .

There is some issue with retrieving of the arr in Activity ListView

**MainActivity**

```
package com.vivekmishra1991.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public int i;

public String arr[] = new String[100];


 private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // A clickable TextView 

    final TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.savedContent);
   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {


            <--ARRAY(arr) RETRIVED FROM DATABASE-->



          Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListVIew.class);
           intent.putExtra("array",arr);
          startActivity(intent);


 }
   });


 }  // onCreate ends here



}
```

**ListView**

```
  <-imports->

public class ListVIew extends Activity {
ListView listview;
Intent intent=getIntent();
String[] arr=intent.getStringArrayExtra("array");
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_list);






listview.findViewById(R.id.list);
     ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>        (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
    listview.setAdapter(Adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting extras from in the oncreate

'getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(String name)'

**edit**

I mistakenly wrote bundle which is another method of passing object through intents.  The method I wrote stores it directly in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to another activity, you can do it using `intent`.

```
Bundle bund = new Bundle();

bund.putString("myKey",name);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);

intent.putExtras(bund);

startActivity(intent);
```

Now in ListView class, receive this data in onCreate()

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      .......

    String nameReceived = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myKey");
}
```

I have given the example of passing String to another activity however, you can pass boolean, int, double etc to another activity. See the full list on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)